# Call variable with $2

Tags: bash

I have a script with around 12 variables that do multiple checks on a user that is passed to my script with `$1`. What I would like to do is to be able to call a variable from the command line with `$2`. So for example I have variables in my script like so:

```
!#bin/bash

var1=blah0
var2=blah1
var3=blah2
var4=blah3
```

What I want is to be able to run the script like `$ ./script.sh user var3` and that should return the value that the variable holds. Without doing a bunch of if then statements, how could I do this efficiently? I've tried arrays but I couldn't figure out how to pass a variable inside the array.

Comment: See also [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Comment: you do not need if conditions , you can use bash indirect referencing.

in your script you can add an echo statement like this and print the value of input variable   |   echo "value of $2 , ${!2}"